# QTP Web Extensibilty - How to force QTP to stop test execution

Tags: qtp, web-extensibility

I'm implementing an extension to QTP using the Web Extensibility Toolkit.
If my JScript function that implements the QTP action encounters an error (e.g User gave wrong argument values), I want the QTP to stop the test execution and notify the user about the error. I want it to act as a normal error in QTP and ask if the user want to debug\retry\skip\stop execution.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you throw an exception with a string then the message you throw is presented in QTP like any other script error (<kbd>Stop</kbd><kbd>Retry</kbd><kbd>Skip</kbd><kbd>Debug</kbd>)

You should throw a JavaScript [`Error` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) so that QTP will be able to display a meaningful message:

```
throw Error("I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do " + action);
```

Comment: When I tried it, I got a message in the explorer saying that: An exception was thrown and not caught. Asking me if I want to debug it.
After pressing no, I get the desired QTP message but the error description is still "An exception was thrown and not caught".

Comment: The exception from explorer is because you don't have `Disable script debugging (Internet Exploere)` checked (from `Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced`) which is the recommended mode when working with QTP.

Comment: With string variables (var e = "error"; throw e;), the whole JS file is not working.
With String literals (throw "error";) I still get the same:
Description: Exception thrown and not caught

Comment: That's strange, try it with `throw "error";` as the only thing on that specific script line (it works for me).